# Understanding AWS S3 Expiration Value in Presigned URL

Tags: amazon-s3, epoch

Can someone help me understand the Expires value?

```
https://pbuserfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/global/a9ea8116-5aa8-4f9f-b35b-5b5049ba9d5f.png
?AWSAccessKeyId=AABBCCDDEEFFXXXX
&Expires=2088028800
&Signature=ASSSDEEE$#l4jvZDMaqqqwerxk%3d
```

What does that represent? I presume seconds from epoch date so this image URL access lapses in about 20 years?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's the date and time when after which the signature on that signed URL is no longer valid, in unix epoch time -- seconds after 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z... about 20 years from now.

Changing this time in the URL to extend its usable life is effectively impossible, since the expiration time itself is also used as part of the input to the HMAC algorithm that generated the signature.

Access will be denied before the expiration if the associated access key id is disabled due to key rotation or if the IAM user associated with that key has its privileges modified such that it no longer has the right to perform a `GET` operation against the object.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks